# Simple way to go check if a request date is within a certain time. Using for loops and if statements

Tags: java, list, spring-mvc, for-loop, if-statement

I have a project where i am creating shifts. Users can request days off so when im creating a shift i want to check if that user has requested that day off. I have used for and if statements to do this but it seems very messy and it doesn't always work. Is there a simpler way to do this?

This is my code for creating a shift.

```
Shift createShift(@RequestBody ShiftParams params)
    {

            User u = userService.findByFirstName(params.text);
        Set<User> userSets = new HashSet<>();
        userSets.add(u);

        List<Request> req = u.getRequests();

        if(req != null && req.isEmpty()) //This creates the shift if 
                                                   the user has no requests
        {
            Shift shift = new Shift();
            shift.setStart(params.start);
            shift.setEnd(params.end);
            shift.setUsersShifts(userSets);
            shiftService.save(shift);   
        }
        else 
        {

        for(Iterator<Request> it= req.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
              Request empReq = it.next();

                 if(empReq.getStatus() == Status.Accepted) 
                {
                 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //for string
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); //for localdate

        //Request start date in LocalDate
        Date d = empReq.getDate();
        String rDateStart = sdf.format(d);
        LocalDate reqStartDate = LocalDate.parse(rDateStart, formatter).minusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Req start date is " + reqStartDate);

        //Request end date in LocalDate
        int numDays = empReq.getNumDays();
        LocalDate endDateReq = reqStartDate.plusDays(numDays).plusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Request finish date is" + endDateReq);

        //Shift start date in LocalDate
        String shiftDate = (params.start).format(formatter);
        LocalDate formatDateTime = LocalDate.parse(shiftDate, formatter);
    System.out.println("Shift date in date format " + formatDateTime); 


        if(formatDateTime.isAfter(reqStartDate) && 
          formatDateTime.isBefore(endDateReq)) //checks is the user has requested day off
{
    System.out.println("The employee has requested that day off");
} else { // if they havent requested that day off the shift is created

        Shift shift = new Shift();
        shift.setStart(params.start);
        shift.setEnd(params.end);
        shift.setUsersShifts(userSets);
        shiftService.save(shift);

    }

      }

  }
return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: params.start is java.util.Date type

```
   public Shift createShift(final @RequestBody ShiftParams params) {

        User u = userService.findByFirstName(params.text);

        Set<User> userSets = Collections.singleton(u);

        List<Request> requests = u.getRequests();

        if ( requests == null || requests.isEmpty() || hasNoDayOffOnShiftDate(requests, params)) //This creates the shift if the user has no requests
        {
            Shift shift = buildShift(params, userSets);
            shiftService.save(shift);
            return shift;
        } 

        return null;
    }

    private boolean hasNoDayOffOnShiftDate(List<Request> requests, ShiftParams params) {
        final LocalDate shiftStartDate = convertToLocalDate(params.start);

        Optional<Request> request = requests
                .stream()
                .filter(req -> req.getStatus() == Status.Accepted)
                .filter(req -> isDayOffOnShiftDate(req, shiftStartDate))
                .findAny();
        return request.isEmpty();
    }

    private boolean isDayOffOnShiftDate(Request empReq, LocalDate shiftStartDate) {
        //Request start date in LocalDate
        LocalDate reqStartDate = convertToLocalDate(empReq.getDate()).minusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Req start date is " + reqStartDate);

        //Request end date in LocalDate
        int numDays = empReq.getNumDays();
        LocalDate endDateReq = reqStartDate.plusDays(numDays).plusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Request finish date is" + endDateReq);

        if (shiftStartDate.isAfter(reqStartDate) &&
                shiftStartDate.isBefore(endDateReq)) //checks is the user has requested day off
        {
            System.out.println("The employee has requested that day off");
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Shift buildShift(@RequestBody ShiftParams params, Set<User> userSets) {
        Shift shift = new Shift();
        shift.setStart(params.start);
        shift.setEnd(params.end);
        shift.setUsersShifts(userSets);
        return shift;
    }

    public LocalDate convertToLocalDate(Date dateToConvert) {
        return LocalDate.ofInstant(
                dateToConvert.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Im trying your way but the problem is its still creating the shift, it acknowledges that the employee has requested the day off but its still creating the shift. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Do you still issue?